# How to enable math coloring with NiceTabularX environment?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, nicematrix

[image]

I want to color all math inside tables with custom color. However, it seems that the command `\RowStyle{\colorInlinedMath}` does not work in the preamble option when using `@`

The definition of `\colorInlinedMath`

```
\newcommand{\colorInlinedMath}{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}\sisetup{color=SpringGreen3}}
```

It is possible to place `\RowStyle{\colorInlinedMath}` before all rows but this is redundant

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\colorInlinedMath}{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}\sisetup{color=SpringGreen3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item In the following figure
        
        \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{\RowStyle{\colorInlinedMath}}r X[l]@{}}
            
             $(a)$ & magnetic domains are oriented randomly
            \\
            
            $(b)$ & magnetic domains are magnetized
            \\
            
            $(c)$ & magnetic domains are fully magnetized
            \\
            
        \end{NiceTabularX}
        
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need `NiceTabularX` for that application to begin with? And why math? Just `\textcolor{SpringGreen3}{(\textit{a})}` would do.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
I guess that you like that all math expression in table be in selected color. This can be simple done insert `\everymath{\color{...}}`in group with table:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item In the following figure
{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}   % <---     
        \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{} rX[l] @{}} 
    $(a)$   & magnetic domains are oriented randomly    \\
    $(b)$   & magnetic domains are magnetized           \\
    $(c)$   & magnetic domains are fully magnetized     \\
        \end{NiceTabularX}
}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]